# Creating a local variable to keep track of months on a calendar in javascript.

Tags: javascript, html, function, logic, global-variables

Here I have below a full html page for a calendar creation, copy it over to see what it does.
I have two buttons below that can increment month by one. My problem is because I can instantiating `var month= date.getMonth()` at the top of the page, the global variable `month` only allows me to increment and decrement  by 1, how can I let `month` be set as a local variable so I am able to increment to more than just 1. Here is the code: I'm sure copy paste will work:

Below I have posted my my button handlers to increase month/decrease month.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

printCalendar(year,month,divDestination);
function printCalendar(year,mth,divDestination){
var currentmonth = mth;
var myOutput=document.getElementById(divDestination)
myOutput.innerHTML=makeCalendar(year,mth)
}
function prevMonth(m){
    m--;
    var currentmonth = m;
    alert(m);
    if(m < 0)
    {
        m = 11;
        year--;
    }

    printCalendar(year,currentmonth,divDestination);
}
function nextMonth(m){
    m++;    
    var currentmonth = m;
    if(m > 11)
    {
        m=0;
        year++;
    }
    printCalendar(year,currentmonth,divDestination);
}
function test(div){
var myOutput=document.getElementById("divCalendar")
myOutput.innerHTML += eventmonth;
}
</script>

<div align="center" id="divCalendar"></div>
<div align="center" id="myButtons">
<input type="button" onclick="test('divCalendar')" value="Say hi" />
<input type="button" onclick="prevMonth(month,'divCalendar')" value="Previous"/>
<input type="button" onclick="nextMonth(month,'divCalendar')" value="Next" />
<input type="button" onclick="printCalendar(year,month,'divCalendar')" value="Reload Calendar" />
```

Here below is my makeCalendar function

```
var myDate = new Date();
    var month = myDate.getMonth();
    var year = myDate.getFullYear();
    var divDestination="divCalendar";

    function leapYear(yr) { 
        if (yr < 1000) yr+=1900
        return((yr%4 == 0) && ((yr%100 == 0) || (yr%400 ==0)))
    }

    function startCol(width, height, color){
        return('<TD WIDTH=' + width + ' HEIGHT=' + height + '>' + '<FONT COLOR="' + color + '">');
    }

    function getHoliday(monthSelected,theday)
    {
        monthSelected = monthSelected + 1
        var holiday = ""
        var HolidayName = new Array (1, 1, "New Year's Day",7, 1, "Canada Day",12, 25, "Christmas Day",12, 26, "Boxing Day", 2,14,"Valentine's Day")
        for(var index = 0; HolidayName.length >= index; index++)
        {   
            if(HolidayName[index] == monthSelected && HolidayName[index+1] == theday)
            {
                holiday = HolidayName[index+2]
            }
        }
        return holiday
    }

    function makeCalendar(yr, mth)
    {
        var monthSelected = mth
        var months    = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
        var days      = new Array(31, leapYear(yr)?29:28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
        var weekDays  = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat")

        var mthSz         = days[mth]
        var mthName       = months[mth]
        var firstDyofMnth = new Date(yr, mth, 1)
        var firstDay      = firstDyofMnth.getDay() + 1
        var numRows       = Math.ceil((mthSz + firstDay-1)/7)
        var mthNameHeight = 50

        var borderWidth   = 2
        var cellSpacing   = 4 
        var cellHeight    = 80 

        var hdrColor      = "midnightblue" 
        var hdrSz         = "+3" 
        var colWidth      = 100 

        var dayCellHeight = 25 
        var dayColor      = "black" 
        var dayCtr        = 1

        // Build the HTML Table 
        var txt = '<CENTER>'
        txt += '<TABLE BORDER=' + borderWidth + ' CELLSPACING=' + cellSpacing + '>' 

        //Show Month Name and Year
        txt += '<TH COLSPAN=7 HEIGHT=' + mthNameHeight + '>' 
        txt += '<FONT COLOR="' + hdrColor + '" SIZE=' + hdrSz + '>' 
        txt += mthName + ' ' + year + '</FONT>' + '</TH>'

        // Show Days of the Week 
        txt += '<TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="center">'
        for (var dy = 0; dy < 7; ++dy) {
            txt += startCol(colWidth, dayCellHeight, dayColor) + weekDays[dy] + '</FONT></TD>' 
        }
        txt += '</TR>'

        // Show Dates in Calendar
        for (var row=1; row <= numRows; ++row) 
        {
            txt += '<TR ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top">'
            for (var col = 1; col <= 7; ++col) 
            {
                if (((col < firstDay) && (row==1)) || (dayCtr>mthSz))
                    {txt += '<TD BGCOLOR="Gainsboro"><BR></TD>'}
                else
                    {
                        var event = getHoliday(monthSelected, dayCtr)
                        txt += '<TD HEIGHT=' + cellHeight + '><FONT COLOR="' + dayColor + '"> <B>'
                        txt += dayCtr
                        txt += '</B></FONT><BR>' + event + '</TD>'
                        dayCtr++;
                    }       
            }
            txt += '</TR>'
        }
        // close all basic table tags and output txt string
        txt += '</TABLE></CENTER>'  
        return txt
        }
```

Comment: Can you trim that code snippet down to just the relevant part for your question? Also, please explain "the global variable month only allows me to increment and decrement by 1". That's kind of odd. How does it prevent you from doing what you want?

Comment: yes I though you might want to see all of it

Comment: It's best to describe the problem as simply as possible, but no simpler.

Comment: I cannot increment my month other than +1 or -1 because my global variable `month` is `date.getMonth()` which mean today, in months is equal to `1`. Now My problem is I am only able to increment towards Jan and March because my global variable `month` is always equal to 1, there fore being able to set a local variable that can keep track of the months I am on as well as the current month of this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to trim this down further to the money bits. Here's basically what you are doing.

```
var month = new Date().getMonth()

var nextMonth = function(m) {
  m++;
  setMonthSomewhere(m);
};

nextMonth(month);
```

So what happens is that you pass your global, which is accessible everywhere anywhere, to the `nextMonth()` function.  And function arguments basically declare a local variable, which is sets to the passed in value.  You now have a global `month` variable set to `1`, and a totally different `m` local to the `nextMonth()` function also set to `1`. You then increment the local variable `m` to `2`, which has no effect on the global variable.

Instead, simply don't pass it in. Manipulate the global directly.

```
var month = new Date().getMonth()

var nextMonth = function() {
  month++;
  setMonthSomewhere(month);
};

nextMonth();
```

Now `nextMonth()` increments the global `month` variable directly, changing it's value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the global variable `month` in your handler `<input type="button" onclick="nextMonth(month,'divCalendar')" value="Next" />` but you never update that global variable.

Why not try removing the first argument from your nextMonth function and instead of using `m` you use month.

```
function nextMonth(){
  month++;    
  if(month > 11)
  {
    month=0;
    year++;
  }
  printCalendar(year,month,divDestination);
}
```

(note your usage of "currentMonth" variable is probably wrong too so I removed that)

But I think that your design is a little flawed - because you are using global variables and putting them on the global namespace, you will have a tough time if you ever need to render 2 calendars or if ever some other javascript wants to use the variable name "month" or "year".

**EDIT (Adding a better solution)**

I would recommend though that instead of passing in numbers to your function, that you pass an entire date object - because that will make the code a lot simpler.

```
function printCalendar(date, divDestination) {
    var myOutput=document.getElementById(divDestination)
    myOutput.innerHTML=makeCalendar(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
}

function nextMonth(date, divDestination) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
    printCalendar(date, divDestination);
}

function prevMonth(date, divDestination) {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1);
    printCalendar(date, divDestination);
}
```

Now because you passed a Date object, the nextMonth and prevMonth functions actually modify the object, so that next time you call the Date will be updated with the new month.

Here is a fiddle that shows the solution using a date object

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmt67/)